# stripe daily payments and send invoices problem

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

We have a project integrated with stripe API and based on the documentation here https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create ... We started to create the customer subscription and sending the whole required parameters and variables with specifying the PlanID is "annual" or "monthly". Once the 1st invoice and its 1st payment created, the subscription status converted to "Active" and that is true and the upcoming invoice creation dates are calculated and scheduled. But the problem here is that the next upcoming invoice doesn't create at its specific date and the auto-renew doesn't work. So, the invoice doesn't mark as paid at all. We understand that the subscription period even it monthly or annually should be created and scheduled automatically once the customer signup with the subscription and then the auto-renew process should start to make the automatic payment of the scheduled created invoice. Your support is highly appreciated in identifying the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reach out to Support with the details - like Invoice IDs, etc - so they can help you debug: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email